# Acer Windows 10 laptop takes min to Shutdown / Sleep / Reboot

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate, reboot, power-management

I have an Acer Inspire 5 running latest Windows 10. I am not sure when exactly, maybe about a month ago, I noticed that it takes a long time (2-3 min) to reboot. Upon close inspection, it seems it also happens to Shutdown and Sleep.

Basically, when I Sleep/Shutdown, the laptop will go through its shutdown process and then screen will go blank as expected. But the "bulb" LED (next to the power LED) does not go away for another 2 min or so.

I have tried turning off hibernation but it didn't help. Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I do not know why it failed. But the issue has gone for good after windows update about a week ago. So I think this issue was introduced via Windows update and subsequently fixed by windows update.